# How to get rid of "Want to save your changes to 'Test.xlsx'" while inserting formula cells into Excel using POI and opening /closing from file system

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am writing numeric cells to a new excel file 'Test.xlsx' using POI.
I first insert 2 rows with 2 columns each with values:

- `Row 1 --> 10 (Cell A1), 20`
- `Row 2 --> 15, 20 (Cell B2)`

For row 3, column 1, I set the formula `SUM(A1:B2)`.

```
XSSFWorkbook wb = null;
String absPath = "C:\excel\Test.xlsx";
File f2 = createFileIfDirExist(absPath); //method will return handle if file created successfully
if (f2 != null) {
    wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("MySheet");
    if (sheet != null) {
        XSSFRow row0 = sheet.createRow(0);
        XSSFCell cell0 = row0.createCell(0);
        cell0.setCellValue(10);
        XSSFCell cell1 = row0.createCell(1);
        cell1.setCellValue(20);

        XSSFRow row1 = sheet.createRow(0);
        XSSFCell cell2 = row1.createCell(0);
        cell2.setCellValue(15);
        XSSFCell cell3 = row1.createCell(1);
        cell3.setCellValue(20);

        XSSFRow row2 = sheet.createRow(0);
        XSSFCell cell4 = row2.createCell(0);
        cell4.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA);
        cell4.setCellFormula("SUM(A1:B2)");

        FileOutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream(new File(f2));
        wb.write(outFile);
        outFile.close();
        f2.close();
        // call method to evaluate formulaEval.evaluateFormulaCell(cell) on every cell in sheet.
    }
}
```

In my actual implementation, i create these sheets, rows and cells dynamically using user input and using loops which I have not used here. It's a basic version of what my code does.

Now, after I run this program, I see that the file is created. I open the file and see that the cell corresponding to cell A3 (formula cell) has the value 65. However, when I close the file, I get the prompt 'want to save your changes to create.xlsx'?
I unzipped create.xlsx before and after clicking on the save for the above prompt and see that the formula cell has the same values for tags F and V in MySheet.xml.
I also noticed that the xml file calcChain.xml is missing before I manually save the excel file and it appears once I save it manually.

Am I missing something to get rid of the prompt when I close the excel? Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.